# How To View 3D Buildings in My Google Maps Application On Android

Tags: android, google-maps

This is the first question on English stackoverflow(I'm a Japanese), so I'm not used to writing English and not good at English.Sorry.

I want to ask about Google Maps API v2 on Android.I created a very simple map application, and I want to show 3D buildings.
I could show a map, but it can not view 3D buildings.

I know that I have to drag two fingers down on the display to show 3D buildings.

This is my code.

```
private void mapInit() {
        isMapInit = true;
        //get LocationManager
        locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //get location information from gps
        Location myLocate = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
        // set map type
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        boolean test = googleMap.isBuildingsEnabled();

        // show the button of now location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
        if(mLocationClient != null){
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }
}
```

I try to show isBuildingsEnabled() value. It was true.
I run my application on Nexus 5 (Android 5.0.1),and it could show 3D buildings on Google Map Android app.

How to view 3D buildings in my application?